# Sum if month is equal to specified date month and if variables are included in list/range

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I'm trying to create a formula to sum if month (column L) corresponds to date in C1 and D1 and if category (column M) is included in list (column I).

I solved the month criteria by using the following formula:

```
(C$1-$K$2)*12+month(C$2&1)
```

I cannot get the list criteria to work. I looked online for hours and tried

- sumifs() - did not work with list as riteria
- sumproduct(sumifs()) - only gave me one value from the list, which depended on positioning
- arrayformula(sumifs())

Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_x9UxzCJ-wydNU92jjqNsp0MfsctGK99r6L7u487Wo0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(K2:N, 
 "select sum(N) 
  where K="&D1&" 
    and L = "&MONTH(D2&1)&"
    and M matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, I2:I)&"'"), 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER($N:$N, $K:$K=C1, $L:$L=MONTH(C2&1), 
 REGEXMATCH($M:$M, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $I$2:$I))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Player0! I made a small alteration to get the formula to work when looking at 2020. The months are stated as e.g., january=13 and february=14 because 2019 is the base, and not as jan=1 and feb=2 which would be more logical. Couldnt have done this without you.

Comment: This is my final formula 
=SUM(FILTER($N:$N,$K:$K=C1, $L:$L=(C$1-$K$2)*12+month(C$2&1), REGEXMATCH($M:$M, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $I$2:$I))))

Comment: Hi Player0! I'm running into a problem when some of the category names (column m) includes parantheses "()". One example could be the name "abc (def)". Would you know how to solve this? If not I might have to transform the source data to exclude parantheses. Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamPontoppidan can you update your sheet sample with such example?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt reply. I have updated the test sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_x9UxzCJ-wydNU92jjqNsp0MfsctGK99r6L7u487Wo0/edit#gid=0 

February 2019 now includes a bracket "()" in the name, which means that the formula in D3 do not pick up and include the value for cell N8.

Comment: @WilliamPontoppidan try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E2TA.png